# Order by @oneToMany field using JPA Specification

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Consider the entities below -

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Phone> phones; //contains both "active" & "inactive" phones
}


@Entity
public class Phone {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  private boolean active;
  private String number;
  
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Employee employee;
}
```

I need to pull all the employees and sort them depending on the count of **"active"** phones they have.
Please note that the employee can have active as well as inactive phones. So the query I am trying to achieve is

```
ORDER BY (SELECT 
        COUNT(phone4_.employee_id)
    FROM
        phone phone4_
    WHERE
        employee4_.id = phone4_.employee_id 
    AND phone4_.active = true
  ) DESC
```

I am stuck with specification here because of some reason and below is the code I have used -

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
orders.add(cb.desc(cb.size(employee.get("phones"))));
cq.orderBy(orders);
```

When I run the code the query that's get generated is

```
ORDER BY (SELECT 
        COUNT(phone4_.employee_id)
    FROM
        phone phone4_
    WHERE
        employee4_.id = phone4_.employee_id) DESC
```

I am unable to add an extra **AND** condition to the logic. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [Persistence API specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1617802524_a33057ba65e46418e76b6039aab79ab9):

> 4.6.16 Subqueries
> Subqueries may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause.

JPA doesn't support subqueries in the order by clause, nor in the select clause.

Hibernate ORM, though, supports them in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses.

So you cannot write that query and being JPA compliant.

This HQL should work though and it's covered by Hibernate ORM:

```
SELECT e1, (SELECT count(p)
            FROM Phone p
            WHERE p.active = true AND p.employee = e1) as activeCount
FROM Employee e1
ORDER BY activeCount DESC
```

Surprisingly, writing this query with criteria doesn't work:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = ormSession.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> criteria = builder.createQuery();
Root<Employee> root = criteria.from( Employee.class );

Subquery<Long> activePhonesQuery = criteria.subquery( Long.class );
Root<Phone> phoneRoot = activePhonesQuery.from( Phone.class );

Subquery<Long> phonesCount = activePhonesQuery
                .select( builder.count( phoneRoot ) )
                .where( builder.and( builder.isTrue( phoneRoot.get( "active" ) ), builder.equal( phoneRoot.get( "employee" ), root ) ) );

criteria.multiselect( root, phonesCount )
    .orderBy( builder.desc( phonesCount ) );
```

The reason is that, Hibernate ORM tries to expand the subquery in the order by clause instead to refer to an alias. And as I mentioned before, this is not supported.

I think the HQL is the easiest option if you don't want to use native queries.

Comment: Thanks @Davide...The above code removes the employees with only inactive phones...I would need to fetch those employees as well...

Comment: Ah, sorry. Get it now

Comment: Which version of Hibernate ORM are you using?

Comment: Apologies @Davide i am unable to format the code here Unfortunately, I can't switch to native query. Stuck with Specification since it's a legacy code I am trying to update. I tried this but it gives me "Unexpected AST node error"

Subquery<Long> subquery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Phone> phRoot= subquery.from(Phone.class);
Predicate p1 = cb.equal(root.get("id"), phRoot.get("employee").get("id"));
Predicate p2 = cb.isTrue(phRoot.get("active"));

cq.distinct(true);
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
orders.add(cb.desc(subquery.select(cb.count(phRoot.get(ID))).where(p1, p2)));

Comment: Not sure about ORM @Davide...I am using latest version of spring boot with dialect as org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Comment: I've added some explanations to my answer. A criteria is just an helper basically to generate an HQL query.  You don't have to use it to be compliant. And in any case, this is not going to work with criteria because of the way subqueries get generated in the order by.